# Field calculation in CPQ steelbricks

Tags: quote, quotelineitem, cpq

I want to do some calculation between some fields before the quote is generated, on Edit Quote Lines page. Do anyone have any idea how to achieve the above requirement. I am totally new with CPQ (steel bricks).

There are 2 custom fields on product object. I need to pick the value from these to fields and need to sum and then divide by quantity. Can we do it with salesforce CPQ? Or we need to go for formula field and do the requirements there.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Price rule can do the calculation on the quote line.
Price Rule Best Practices - https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Prices-Discounts-Knowledge-Base/Price-Rule-Best-Practices/ta-p/13619